# ImportError: cannot import name 'UsersClient'

Tags: python-3.x, okta

cannot import UsersClient from okta

installed

- python 3.6
- okta 1.0.3

```
line 4:  from okta import UsersClient

okta_client = UsersClient("https://xxxx.okta.com", "XXXXX...")
```

File "/Users/vikkes/garage/borse/backend/src/app.py", line 4, in 
from okta import UsersClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'UsersClient'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The okta version is the problem. The code works with the older okta version. Use okta version ***0.0.4***.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not downgrade.  Never downgrade your component for anything related security or auth unless there is a very good reason.

They changed **UsersClient** to **okta.client.Client**.

You could update your code this way

```
from okta.client import Client as UsersClient

client_config = {
                 "orgUrl": "https://geddylee.rush.toronto",
                 "token": "yyzyyzyyzyyzyyzyyz"     
                 }
okta_client = UsersClient(client_config)
```